# How to Transpose table in vaadin?

Tags: vaadin, transpose

I need to rotate (Transpose) com.vaadin.ui.Table in vaadin. Headers should be first colum.
Ofcourse i can hide headers, convert all parameters to String, and fill first columns by parameters names, second column by first object's parameters, etc...

But it wrong way.

Comment: You have to do it manually, there is no such function available in the vaadin table

Comment: The solution will largely depend on an underlying DataSource. The only approach that will work for a general case is to dump all the data (including cache and generated columns) in two-dimensional array and then transpose it. You think it's a wrong way and so do I.